# Is it required to change OAuth endpoints based on custom domain?

Tags: oauth2

We have done integration between .net application and Salesforce.

Currently we are using the primary OAuth endpoints from .net application for authentication:

For production:

For authorization: login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize
For token requests: login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
For revoking OAuth tokens: login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/revoke

For sandbox:

Instead of login.salesforce.com used test.salesforce.com

If I want to integrate .net application with a salesforce org on which custom domain has set up then do I need to change the above urls based on custom domain for each such org?

Can anyone please suggest what are the best practices for handling this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only if you have disabled login from login.salesforce.com or test.salesforce.com(You can check that in Setup>My domain), otherwise you can use the endpoints you are using and in return you will get a instance url which is the domain where subsequent requests should go.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it's not required to change the initial endpoints when using a custom domain, as detailed [in this post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BCgvIAG)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE @ReadyPlayer1! Can you post some of the relevant content from that link? Links tend to break over time making answers without details a bit useless in the long term :)